# Multiply Number typed into a column by 6

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Okay this is probably really simple to do but I just can't find anything on it online.

What I am trying to do is if I type 4 into a column the 4 will be multiplied by 6 and changed. Basically i don't want 4 to be there anymore but to be replaced by the answer to 4*6 (24). (Not only 4 by the way, thats just an example)

I need it all in the same column.

Is there a way to do this so Excel will change the typed number automatically when a new one is input.

Hopefully this makes sense, if not let me know and I can elaborate further.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with VBA solution, following will help:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'will work for Column A
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent change event to fire
    On Error GoTo Err 'to re-enable the events
    Target.Value = Target.Value * 6
Err:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Instead of

```
If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

you can also use

```
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
```